# Jasper report column is too large to display on single page

Tags: jasper-reports

I have table with several column's. One of them is in some case extra large (for example contains 800 character, and other columns contains about 50-100 characters).

Column data contains multiple text lines, where each line has linebreak at the end. I suppose it does not fit on single page based on column width. So, when data is displayed, when such large column comes, on column data.first page I got whole column empty, not a single character in that column in displayed, and on second page is only displayed last line of that text.
Does anybody know why this happens and how to fix it? I cannot change column width because of the other columns.

Can I set some option on *JasperReports* to override such behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is managed by the splitType attribute of the band: http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/type/SplitTypeEnum.html.